# Two instances of the same element seem to share state

Tags: reactjs

In my `React` application I have a `Collapsible` component that I use more than once, like so:

```
const [openFAQ, setOpenFAQ] = React.useState("");

const handleFAQClick = (question: string) => {
  if (question === openFAQ) {
    setOpenFAQ("");
  } else {
    setOpenFAQ(question);
  }
};

return ({
  FAQS.map(({ question, answer }, index) => (
    <Collapsible
      key={index}
      title={question}
      open={openFAQ === question}
      onClick={() => handleFAQClick(question)}
    >
      {answer}
    </Collapsible>
  ))
})
```

And the `Collapsible` element accepts `open` as a prop and does not have own state:

```
export const Collapsible = ({
  title,
  open,
  children,
  onClick,
  ...props
}: Props) => {
  return (
    <Container {...props}>
      <Toggle open={open} />
      <Title onClick={onClick}>{title}</Title>
      <Content>
        <InnerContent>{children}</InnerContent>
      </Content>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

However, when I click on the second `Collapsible`, the first one opens... I can't figure out why.

A working example is available in a sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-monad-ccfzp?file=/src/Collapsible.tsx:967-1282).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on `Collapsible.tsx` line 36, the `input` `id` is set the same for both the Collapsibles. you need to make them different from each other and the problem would be solved.

Comment: Perhaps we were viewing this at the same time. hehe

Comment: I'm sure this is it... :)

Answer (score 3):

You will need to ensure that the label and id for each checkbox is the same. Here's a working [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-thompson-v50pp)

But if you're trying to implement an accordion style, you may need another approach.

Comment: Thanks, you were right! The example was really helpful as well. I accepted Danoosh's answer though, he was first, plus, he's a new contributor - have to support new people :)

Answer (score 1):

One thing is that you have the same id which is wrong BUT it can still work. Just change the checkbox input from 'defaultChecked={...}' to 'checked={...}'.
The reason is that, if you use defaultSomething - it tells react that even if this value will be changed - do not change this value in the DOM - https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#default-values

> Changing the value of defaultValue attribute after a component has mounted will not cause any update of the value in the DOM

Comment: Thanks Adrian, your answer kind of works as well. Only when changing `defaultChecked` to `checked`, the console logs a warning `Warning: You provided a checked prop to a form field without an onChange handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use defaultChecked. Otherwise, set either onChange or readOnly.`

Comment: @artooras - you are right. Looks like you can remove this warning/error by adding onChange={()=>{}} ;). This is because now the value of the field depends on the state of the app - so this conflicts with the real user input. Now when I am thinking about this solution I can see that I do not fully understand why it behaved so strangely in first place (first question selected) so my explanation may be wrong/not full. But looks like it works. Edit. Ok probably because of this second issue - the ID